# Setting onClick to false

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I currently have a table using a slider to provide additional details for a table. When the slider component opens I have an X to close to the slider. I am attempting to have that X close the slider and have the table in its original form appear.

Here is a code sandbox: 
[code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-cgynm?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Slider component :

```
function ExpandToggle(isOpenProps) {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Button>
        <ArrowForwardIosIcon size="small" onClick={toggle} />{" "}
      </Button>
      <SliderInfo open={isOpen} />
    </>
  );
}
```

SliderInfo component with `onClick={open=false}`

```
export default function SliderInfo({ open }) {
  const classes = useStyles();



  return (
    <Slide direction="left" in={open} mountOnEnter unmountOnExit>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Grid container>
          <Grid item>
            <Typography variant="h6">Vanila Ice Cream</Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <Typography variant="h6">Chocolate Ice Cream</Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <Typography variant="h6">Strawberry Ice Cream</Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <Typography variant="h6">Sherbert </Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <Typography variant="h6">None</Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <Button>
              <CloseIcon onClick={open=false} />
            </Button>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </div>
    </Slide>
```

On `CloseIcon` I have an onClick that i'm trying to set open which is passed from `Slider` to false so it can close the slider component. At the moment upon clicking on the `CloseIcon` it is not do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't modify props directly.

Pass in the toggle function just like you passed in the open variable, and call it instead.

```js
<SliderInfo open={isOpen} toggleOpen={toggle} />

// In Sliderinfo
export default function SliderInfo({ open, toggleOpen }) {
...
<CloseIcon onClick={toggleOpen} />
```

If your toggle doesn't serve the same purpose, create a new function that only sets `isOpen` to false and use it instead.

Also remember that `onClick` expects a function. So the `open=false` is actually getting executed during render, not after a click. Correct inline format would be `onClick={(e) => {//do stuff}}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a callback function to the `Slider` that can call your `setIsOpen` state modifier, and then pass it to `onClick`:

```
function ExpandToggle(isOpenProps) {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Button>
        <ArrowForwardIosIcon size="small" onClick={toggle} />{" "}
      </Button>
      <SliderInfo open={isOpen} onRequestClose={() => { setIsOpen(false) }} />
    </>
  );
}

export default function SliderInfo({ open, onRequestClose }) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Slide direction="left" in={open} mountOnEnter unmountOnExit>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Grid container>
          <Grid item>
            <Typography variant="h6">Vanila Ice Cream</Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <Typography variant="h6">Chocolate Ice Cream</Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <Typography variant="h6">Strawberry Ice Cream</Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <Typography variant="h6">Sherbert </Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <Typography variant="h6">None</Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <Button>
              <CloseIcon onClick={onRequestClose} />
            </Button>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </div>
    </Slide>
```